# Calculating algorithm complexity using Big O

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am trying to calculate the complexity of different variations of an algorithm using Big O.

A simplified description of the algorithm follows:

Let's consider a "converter" a function that takes certain object and transforms it to another representation. Each converter defines its domain and range.

There is a routine that takes a source object (i.e., an object to convert), a list of converter functions and the expected type of the conversion.

It iterates on the converters list until it finds a converter whose domain and range are compatible with the object to convert and the expected conversion type.

As far as I know, the complexity of this should be O(n), since it directly depends on the number of converters.

Now, what would be the complexity if each converter may need to recursively invoke the conversion routine certain number of times ?

For example, it may need to convert certain components of the source object to other objects that will be later assembled as the object to return (the target of the original conversion).

As I understand it, informally this gives:

```
n + m1( n + m2 (n + m3 (...)) ) )
```

Where:

- n is a measure of the effort to find the original converter.
- m1 the number of source object subcomponents that should be converted by the conversion routine.
- m2 the maximum number of subcomponents from the original m1 objects.
- etc ...

As an additional detail, the number of subcomponents to convert should decrease on each recursive invocation.

Is this correct ? If so how should I reduce this formula to Big O notation ?

Finally, what would be the complexity if there is a sort of intelligent indexing system that allows me to quickly find the right converter function in the converters list ?
As far as I understand, in the simplest case where a converter does not invoke the conversion function recursively, this should be O(log n) , correct ?.

But what would be the complexity of the indexing-based algorithm if each converter, as in the previous case, may need to recursively invoke the conversion function ?

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, the complexity of this should be O(n), since it directly depends on the number of converters.

Not necessarily. Asymptotic complexity has to do with the size of your input (in bytes). If your object has a constant size then the total input size (your N) will asymptotically be proportional to the number of converters so iterating over them will be O(N). On the other hand, if your object is big -- say, an m by m matrix, where m is the number of converters -- then your N will be proportional to m^2 and the iteration will be O(m), which is only O(sqrt(n)). Another important case is when the number of converters is bounded by a constant instead of being something that the caller can set as high as he wants - in the case the iteration is O(1).

> Now, what would be the complexity if each converter may need to recursively invoke the conversion routine certain number of times ?

Hard to tell without knowing what the converters do. For all we know, they might enter an infinite loop and never return a result.

> As I understand it, this gives
>
> ```
> n + m1( n + m2 (n + m3 (...)) ) )
> ```

Not necessarily, first of all, the inner calls might not be n since the object size or converter list might have changed.

Also, currently your formula is kind of informal. You should try converting it into a real recurrence.

---

Going back to your question, I'm getting the impression that your object is kind of like a tree of nodes and that you traverse this tree to convert int into something else. In this case it might be easier to find the complexity by looking at your datastructures instead of by trying to make a recurrence. For example, if we know that each node of the initial object ends up being processed once, then (assuming we have n nodes) our total runtime will be n times the cost to process a single node. If processing a node is dominated by the time it takes to find a converter, than the complexity for processing a node is O(m), where m is the number of converters. On the other hand, if the cost to proccess that node (after you already converted the child nodes) is bigger than that then you ignore the cost of finding the converter and use this instead.

Assuming that proccessing a node once you proccessed the children is cheap (say, constant time) then our total time complexity is O(n*m) where n is the number of nodes and m is the number of converters. Now we just need to convert this to something in terms of N. If both n and m are O(n) (taht is, both the object and converter list as big as we want) then the complexity will be O(N^2). If the object is as big as we want (n is O(N)) but the converter list has limited size (m is O(1)) then n*m is O(N). And so on.